# Add ID to GridView Row

Tags: asp.net

How to add ID to GridView rows (IDs should be rendered)?

I am using .NET (C#). I have GridView control.

I have some javascript functions that are manipulating table rows, but it is necessary to have IDs for those rows:

```
<table>
    <tr id=1> ...  
    <tr id=2> ...  //id should come from database
..
```

My GridView is genereted from Data from DataBase. It is important not to have FAKE ROW IDS, but really row ids from DB (there are some ajax javascript function that updates DB based on those IDs and user manipulations with table).

Part of my GridView is the following:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdNews" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" RowStyle-BorderStyle="None"
                GridLines="None" CssClass="table" Style="white-space: nowrap" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="ID" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="true" OnSorting="grdNews_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="grdNews_RowDataBound">
                <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="nodrag" />
                <Columns>
                ....
```

I have tried the following:

```
 protected void grdNews_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.ID = grdNews.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
     }
}
```

This gives e.Row.ID the correct value, but this doesn't render this ID.

So, how to render IDs from DataBase for Rows in GridView?

Comment: If you just want to assign the index of the row, why you need to assign it as property? You could also access the n-th row of the table from clientside.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try following....

```
protected void grdNews_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        row.Attributes["id"] =grdNews.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();


      }
 }
```

Comment: This could very easily cause ID duplicates on the client side. Combining the DataKey with ClientID would solve it. Or, one could use data-xxx-id as attribute instead.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a hidden-field which you can access from client- and from server-side.

```
<Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField >
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      ....
</Columns>
```

Comment: I do not want to rewrite existing js function, but they already works with <tr id="..."> and not with hidden fields. THis could be an option, if the above answer doesn't work, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net code

```
  Private Sub gvPayments_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvPayments.RowDataBound

    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    For Each oItem As GridViewRow In gvPayments.Rows

        counter += 1
        oItem.Cells(1).Text = counter.ToString()
        oItem.Attributes("id") = "tr_" + counter.ToString

    Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. You are calling your database Binding function out side the IsPOstback event.
2. You have not mentioned your RowDatabound Event Signature in Grid Definition